# How can I rectify error "undefined reference to __mutex_lock_slowpath" during kernel compilation?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am compiling kernel version 2.6.25 on Ubuntu 12.04.When I compile it using "make" command.

I get errors:

kernel/built-in.o: In function `mutex_lock':

/usr/src/linux-2.6.25/kernel/mutex.c:92: undefined reference to `__mutex_lock_slowpath'

kernel/built-in.o: In function `mutex_unlock':

/usr/src/linux-2.6.25/kernel/mutex.c:117: undefined reference to `__mutex_unlock_slowpath'

make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1

How can I rectify these errors? Please help

Comment: Those function defined in same file only. do u have forward declaration for them???

Comment: @Rajeev Das were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: I couldn't solve it. Please share the information

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the solution is to change `kernel/mutex.c` in four locations:

lines 60, 96, 192

```
-static void fastcall noinline __sched
+static __attribute__ ((used)) void fastcall noinline __sched
```

line 251

```
-static fastcall noinline void
+static __attribute__ ((used)) void fastcall noinline __sched
```

I don't know why `__used` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to change the declarations in kernel/mutex.c to enforce that the functions are to be retained in the object file. You can use the gcc attribute extension "__used" like this:

```
-static void noinline __sched
+static __used void noinline __sched
 __mutex_lock_slowpath(atomic_t *lock_count);

-static noinline void __sched __mutex_unlock_slowpath(atomic_t *lock_count);
+static __used noinline void __sched __mutex_unlock_slowpath(atomic_t *lock_count);
```

Comment: That solution dows not work:

    kernel/mutex.c:60:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
    static __used void fastcall noinline __sched
                       ^